# Custom Id in Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my model I need an ID field that is different from the default ID given by Django. I need my IDs in the following format: [year][ascending number]

*Example: `2021001`,`2021002`,`2021003`*

The IDs shall not be editable but model entries shall take the year for the ID from a DateTimeField in the model. I am unsure if I use a normal Django ID and also create some kind of additional ID for the model or if I replace the normal Django ID with a [Custom ID](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is pretty similar to one I had solved for a previous project of mine. What I had done for this was to simply use the default id for the primary key, while using some extra fields to make the composite identifier needed.

To ensure the uniqueness and the restarting of the count I had made a model which would (only by the logic, no actual constraints) only have one row in it. Whenever a new instance of the model which needs this identifier would be created this row would be updated in a transaction and it's stored value would be used.

The implementation of it is as follows:

```
from django.db import models, transaction

import datetime


class TokenCounter(models.Model):
    counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    last_update = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_new_token(cls):
        with transaction.atomic():
            token_counter = cls.objects.select_for_update().first()
            if token_counter is None:
                token_counter = cls.objects.create()
            if token_counter.last_update.year != datetime.date.today().year:
                token_counter.counter = 0
            token_counter.counter += 1
            token_counter.save()
            return_value = token_counter.counter
        return return_value

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            self.__class__.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk).delete()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Next suppose you need to use this in some other model:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    yearly_token = models.IntegerField(default=TokenCounter.get_new_token)

    @property
    def token_number(self):
        return '{}{}'.format(self.created_at.year, str(self.yearly_token).zfill(4))
    
    @classmethod
    def get_from_token(cls, token):
        year = int(token[:4])
        yearly_token = int(token[4:])
        try:
            obj = cls.objects.get(created_at__year=year, yearly_token=yearly_token)
        except cls.DoesNotExist:
            obj = None
        return obj
```

---

**Note**: This might not be very refined as the code was written when I was very inexperienced, and there may be many areas where it can be refined. For example you can add a `unique_for_year` in the `yearly_token` field so:

```
yearly_token = models.IntegerField(default=TokenCounter.get_new_token, unique_for_year='created_at')
```